# Saving a CSV file in Processing with Android mode

Tags: android, csv, processing

I'd want to save the Highscore of my game.
I use a Csv file which is stored in the data folder.

Loading the file works fine but when I want to store the new Highscore it doesn't saves it. But there is also no Error.

To save the file I use the command:

```
saveTable(table, "Highscore.csv");
```

It is important for me to save it in Internal Storage

edit: 
Now I try to save it in external Storage
but I didn`t found any good explanation how to do this in Processing

And where do I have to put a file which already exists when I use it in external Storage

External storage permissions are already activatet

I hope there is an easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: hi Julius, I believe there is this thing where you can read from your csv but cannot write to it. It is read only. You need to make sure you put your file in a folder where you can read and write.

Comment: Your question description looks a bit vague. Do you want help on how to create the CSV using Processing, or storing the created csv into the Internal Storage?

Comment: Sorry, my Main Problem is to save some Data on android with processing . After a bit of reaserch  I think it is also okay when I save the Data external. But I didnt found a good way to do this.